# How to redirect HTTPS to HTTP without SSL Cert

Tags: linux, .htaccess, http, ssl, google-search-console

I have a site and when I search it in Google, I found the links starts with "https" (which would cause some warning page).

The link actually works with "http", and I never intend to use any "https" for my  website.

How do I avoid it?. OR How to redirect HTTPS to HTTP without SSL Cert.

Answer (score 0):

> How to redirect HTTPS to HTTP without SSL Cert.

You can't. No way. No workaround.

Redirection is done at the HTTP level, which means after the SSL handshake is done. Thus you need first a successful SSL handshake and for this you need to have a valid certificate.

> when I search it in Google, I found the links starts with "https" (which would cause some warning page).

This is probably because your site is on a server which have multiple sites and which have https on some of these sites. This means that the server is listening on port 443 (https) for connections and will provide some default certificate which does not match the site (which causes the warning).

Your only choice is to either get a certificate for this site or move to a server which does not even listen for https connections.